# ¿Cómo se haría este código Java en Dart?

Tags: java, flutter, dart

Este método void ejecuta un Runnable (), pero ¿cómo sería en Dart?

Código Java:

```
public void flush(final QueuedCommand command) {
    this.executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            try {
              command.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              Flusher.this.logger.info("Failed to flush", e);
            } 
          }
        });
  }
```

executorService es un package de Dart: https://pub.dev/packages/executorservices
* Lo que hay dentro del catch ya está solucionado, solo que sigo sin saber como hacer el runnable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo mismo en Dart sería así:

```dart
void flush(QueuedCommand command) {
    executorService.submitAction(() {
      try {
        command.flush();
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        print("Failed to flush , $e");
      }
    }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo estaba haciendo parecido pero no daba con la clave y era el submitAction... xD

Comment: No hay problema, te recomiendo leer la documentación del package siempre y muchas veces su repositorio tiene ejemplos que puedes usar.

Comment: Losé pero no sé porque no lo veía. Una pregunta si no te importa, sabes porqué esto **Map<Request, CacheEntry> cache = new HashMap();** no me da la posibilidad de hacer esto **this.cache.get()** ? NOTA: Request es una clase abstracta y CacheEntry es una clase normal con datetime, responses y poco más

Comment: tendriá que ver que hacía el método get en java? en Dart puedes acceder directamente a los valores, quizas si creas otra pregunta te puedo ayudar

Comment: Vale voy a crear otra pregunta a ver si me puedes ayudar